# django : using if else or while else inside Sum function with annotation? Cannot compute Sum('<CombinedExpression:..') is an aggregate

Tags: python, mysql, django

i want to set a condition to my `Sum` function inside `annotate`  , and i tried to use `Case` `When` but it didnt work in my case

this is my models.py

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.IntegerField()

class Prodcut(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_lenth=20)
    cost = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.IntegerField()
```

i want to something like this

```
total = F('price')*F('order')
base = (F(name__cost')+F('name__price')) * F('order')
if  total> base:
    income = Sum(F('total') - F('base'))
```

i tried this

```
MyModel.objects.values('name__name').annotate(total=(Sum(F('price') * F('order'),output_field=IntegerField())),
                        base=(Sum((F('name__price')+F('name__cost'))*F('order'),output_field=IntegerField())
                            ),
                        income=Sum(
                            Case(When(total__gt=F('base') , then=Sum(F('total') - F('base'))),default=0),output_field=IntegerField()),)
```

but this raise this error:

> Cannot compute Sum('<CombinedExpression: F(total) - F(base)>'): '<CombinedExpression: F(total) - F(base)>' is an aggregate

i dont want to use `.filter(income__gt=0)` because it stops `quantity` from counting
and i dont want to counting `income` to those products which loss its sold
for example

i make a post on `MyModel(name=mouse ,order=2,price=20)` and in my Product model i have these information for mouse product `Product(name=mouse,cost=4,price=10)` , when i calculate to find income for this product : `(2 *20) - ((4+10)*2) => 40 - 28 = 12` , but sometimes happen the result will be a negative price when `(2*10) - ((4+10)*2) => 20 - 28 = -8`

*i use mysql v:8 for database

i want to prevent negative numbers to add to my `income` with respect the other columns `quantity`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot use an aggregate (total and base) inside yet another aggregate in the same query. There is only one GROUP BY clause and Django cannot automatically produce a valid query here. As far as I've understood, you need to firstly calculate total and base, find each MyModel income, and only then produce an aggregate:

```
MyModel.objects.annotate(
    total=F('price') * F('order'),
    base=(F('name__price') + F('name__cost')) * F('order'),
    income=Case(
        When(total__gt=F('base'), then=F('total') - F('base')),
        default=0,
        output_field=IntegerField()
    )
).values('name__name').annotate(income=Sum('income'))
```

P.S. Please, format your code so people can read it without difficulties :)

P.P.S I can probably see another way, you don't need Sum() for the income because total and base are sums already

```
MyModel.objects.values('name__name').annotate(
    total=Sum(F('price') * F('order')),
    base=Sum((F('name__price') + F('name__cost')) * F('order')),
).annotate(
    income=Case(
        When(total__gt=F('base'), then=F('total') - F('base')),
        default=0,
        output_field=IntegerField()
    )
)
```

Comment: i cant appreciate enough , you saved my day

Answer (score 1):

Try this, maybe some twists needed, idea is using [Conditional Expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-expressions)

```
from django.db.models import Case, When, Value, IntegerField

MyModel.objects.values('name__name').annotate(
       total = F('price')*F('order')
       base = (F('name__cost') + F('name__price')) * F('order')
    ).annotate(
       income = Case(
          When(total__gt=F('base'), then=Sum(F('total')-F('base'))
    ), default = F('total'), output_field=IntegerField())
)
```

Comment: thanks , i tried it also , but it raise this error (Cannot compute Sum('<CombinedExpression: F(total) - F(base)>'): '<CombinedExpression: F(total) - F(base)>' is an aggregate